# Writing blank on canvas using fillText

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chart.js

I have a chart.js Donut chart in the center of which I have to show a value.There is a date field which refreshes the chart thereby affecting the central value.

```
var text = dataTxt,
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;
    ctx.fillText(" ", textX, textY);//attempting to write blank value.
    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY); //this writes the value.
    ctx.save();
```

Problem is that on subsequent update of the chart the central area is not cleared & the value gets written over the old one.

For this I added the line `ctx.fillText(" ", textX, textY);` in above code but to no effect.
Any Ideas on how to clear up the area before the text is written there?

There is a HTML/CSS solution to write the data in the center but I cant use that since it doesnt export the central data when chart is downloaded as PNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical use cases people don't attempt to "undo" their changes on the Canvas - it's far easier to just clear the Canvas and start drawing all over again.

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// Do my drawing again
myChart.update(); // With chart.js this triggers a redraw.
```

In your case I think you're making the mistake of thinking that the Canvas saves the text image and lets you alter it in subsequent drawings. Think of it like Microsoft Paint - once that text is on the image, you're not going to be able to get rid of it easily without undo'ing.

Comment: I was trying to write a blank string on that particular area every time when the writing code is called.I was expecting `ctx.fillText(" ", textX, textY);` to do so since ` textX,textY` are the same coordinates on which the data gets written.Is this not correct?

Comment: @techie_28 how do you expect a blank string to be displayed? It would be rendered as... nothing?